# Complexity of computing symmetries of a polynomial

Tags: complexity-theory, polynomials

Given a polynomial $f\in\mathbb{F}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ what is the computational complexity of computing a generating set of the automorphism group of $f$? On first look this seems like a hard problem (at the least NP-hard). Is the complexity of the above problem studied earlier?

Comment: "the automorphism group of $\hspace{.04 in}$f" in the sense of ​ ​ ​ [permutation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix) or [signed permutation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_permutation_matrix#Signed_permutation_group) or [generalized permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_permutation_matrix) or [vector space automorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphism#Examples) or [affine automorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space#Ring_of_polynomial_functions) ​ ? ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: In any case, it seems like the group can easily have lots of [generating sets with the minimum number of elements], and even [closed-under-inverse generating sets with the minimum number of elements for such generating sets], so "the generating set" probably needs clarification. ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer I guess the OP means "a generating set".

Comment: How is the polynomial given to you? Also, does there always exist a small generating set?

Comment: Also, what field $\mathbb{F}$ are you working in?  Are you working in a finite field?  In $\mathbb{Q}$?  Something else?  This might affect the result, so include as much information as you can in your question.